# Sensenet : Can I store lucene index files on azure file storage instead of App_Data folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene.net, sensenet

I have setup `SenseNet 6.3 Community Edition` on my `web application` based on `Asp.net with C#`.

Currently there is `lucene Index files` are being stored in `App_Data` folder on web server on which my web app hosted.

Is there any way to store the `lucene index file` `remotely (another web server)` or `Azure file storage`?

If yes then how and what are the cons of that?

I can see `IndexDirectoryPath` `webconfig setting` to store `lucene index files` to another place but how to use it with `remote location`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: *not recommended*.

It depends on why do you want to store the index elsewhere. The configuration you mentioned was created to let you store the index in a different folder, you can freely do that of course. It can point to a remote drive on a file server (e.g. `\\myserver\remotefolder`), if you are willing to sacrifice some speed. Because sensenet extensively uses the index, it is recommended that the index is stored locally to avoid network file access.

But if you wanted to move the index to a shared drive so that *other* app domains (other web nodes) have access to it - that is not possible. **The index can be read and written by a single app domain exclusively**. To let multiple web nodes work on the same content repository, you'll have to configure communication ([MSMQ](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Communication_between_appdomains)) between app domains.

Because of the same reasons, Azure file storage is also not recommended, Lucene needs a real file system that can be accessed very fast.